# Improving JMS message consumption speed of application

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

We have an application which can consume around 300 JMS messages per minute. We need to increase the speed to 3000 messages per minute.

I created a simple test program which reads the messages from the queue and logs the messages. No processing is involved, so I expected a high speed. However, the logging is still happening at a speed of around 400 messages per minute.

Below are the excerpts of my program

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="testJmsInboundAdapter" 
    auto-startup="true"
    destination="testQueueDestination" 
    connection-factory="testConnectionFactory" 
    channel="messageTransformerChannel" />

<int:channel id="messageTransformerChannel" />

<int:service-activator 
    id="loggerActivator"
    input-channel="messageTransformerChannel" 
    method="log"
    ref="logger" />
```

The logger method simply logs the message

```
public void log(final GenericMessage<Object> object) {
        LOGGER.info("Logging message" + object);
    }
```

Any advise where should I look at the bottleneck. Is there any limitation on the number of messages that can be consumed per minute using spring integration's message-driven-channel-adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to these options:

```
<xsd:attribute name="concurrent-consumers" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Specify the number of concurrent consumers to create. Default is 1.
                    Specifying a higher value for this setting will increase the standard
                    level of scheduled concurrent consumers at runtime: This is effectively
                    the minimum number of concurrent consumers which will be scheduled
                    at any given time. This is a static setting; for dynamic scaling,
                    consider specifying the "maxConcurrentConsumers" setting instead.
                    Raising the number of concurrent consumers is recommendable in order
                    to scale the consumption of messages coming in from a queue. However,
                    note that any ordering guarantees are lost once multiple consumers are
                    registered
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="max-concurrent-consumers" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                 Specify the maximum number of concurrent consumers to create. Default is 1.
                     If this setting is higher than "concurrentConsumers", the listener container
                     will dynamically schedule new consumers at runtime, provided that enough
                     incoming messages are encountered. Once the load goes down again, the number of
                     consumers will be reduced to the standard level ("concurrentConsumers") again.
                     Raising the number of concurrent consumers is recommendable in order
                    to scale the consumption of messages coming in from a queue. However,
                    note that any ordering guarantees are lost once multiple consumers are
                    registered.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks, using concurrent-consumer="5" increased the processing speed to 2k messages per minute

Comment: Can you explain how does concurrent-consumer property work. If I set concurrent-consumer value to 5, does it create 5 threads which start reading from the JMS queue simultaneously.                                                    Also, if the logger bean which eventually consumes the messages retrieved in the above example is of scope prototype- will a different logger bean be created for each thread or will all threads refer to the same logger bean

Comment: Yes, they will do that simultaneously. Logger bean will be created only once for the Service Activator endpoint and only during application start app. Everything rest, please, read on the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrency(String concurrency)` JavaDocs.